# Regex: Match all hyphens or underscores not at the beginning or the end of the string

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am writing some code that needs to convert a string to camel case. However, I want to allow any `_` or `-` at the beginning of the code.

I have had success matching up an `_` character using the regex here:

```
^(?!_)(\w+)_(\w+)(?<!_)$
```

when the inputs are:

```
pro_gamer #matched
#ignored
_proto 
proto_
__proto
proto__
__proto__
#matched as nerd_godess_of, skyrim
nerd_godess_of_skyrim
```

> I recursively apply my method on the first match if it looks like `nerd_godess_of`.

I am having troubled adding `-` matches to the same, I assumed that just adding a `-` to the mix like this would work:

```
^(?![_-])(\w+)[_-](\w+)(?<![_-])$
```

and it matches like this:

```
super-mario #matched
eslint-path #matched
eslint-global-path #NOT MATCHED.
```

I would like to understand why the regex fails to match the last case given that it worked correctly for the `_`.

The (almost) full set of test inputs can be found [here](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/code-katas/blob/master/camel_case/spec/camel_case_spec.rb)

Comment: Check [this approach](http://ideone.com/oT31P2). I understand: 1) the string must match the specified format (consequent `-` or `_` (but not `-_` or `_-`) in between alphanumeric chars only), 2) if the format does not match, return the string, else upcase the letter after `_` or `-`.

Comment: So, is my understanding correct? Or are you just  after something like [this](http://ideone.com/ZuODdh)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that

```
^(?![_-])(\w+)[_-](\w+)(?<![_-])$
```

does not match the second hyphen in "eslint-global-path" is because of the anchor `^` which limits the match to be on the first hyphen only. This regex reads, "Match the beginning of the line, not followed by a hyphen or underscore, then match one or more words characters (including underscores), a hyphen or underscore, and then one or more word characters in a capture group. Lastly, do not match a hyphen or underscore at the end of the line."

The fact that an underscore (but not a hyphen) is a word (`\w`) character completely messes up the regex. In general, rather than using `\w`, you might want to use `\p{Alpha}` or `\p{Alnum}` (or POSIX `[[:alpha:]]` or `[[:alnum:]]`).

Try this.

```
r = /
    (?<=     # begin a positive lookbehind
      [^_-]  # match a character other than an underscore or hyphen
    )        # end positive lookbehind
    (        # begin capture group 1
      (?:    # begin a non-capture group
        -+   # match one or more hyphens
        |    # or
        _+   # match one or more underscores
      )      # end non-capture group
      [^_-]  # match any character other than an underscore or hyphen
    )        # end capture group 1
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode

'_cats_have--nine_lives--'.gsub(r) { |s| s[-1].upcase }
  #=> "_catsHaveNineLives--"
```

This regex is conventionally written as follows.

```
r = /(?<=[^_-])((?:-+|_+)[^_-])/
```

If all the letters are lower case one could alternatively write

```
'_cats_have--nine_lives--'.split(/(?<=[^_-])(?:_+|-+)(?=[^_-])/).
  map(&:capitalize).join
  #=> "_catsHaveNineLives--"
```

where

```
'_cats_have--nine_lives--'.split(/(?<=[^_-])(?:_+|-+)(?=[^_-])/)
  #=> ["_cats", "have", "nine", "lives--"]
```

`(?=[^_-])` is a positive lookahead that requires the characters on which the split is made to be followed by a character other than an underscore or hyphen

Answer (score 0):

you can try the regex

```
^(?=[^-_])(\w+[-_]\w*)+(?=[^-_])\w$
```

see the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/pj34Ed/1).

Answer (score -1):

Switch `_-` to `-_` so that `-` is not treated as a range op, as in `a-z`.

Comment: I had that thought, it does not seem to make a difference either way http://rubular.com/r/LhHoSHuO8S

Comment: `-` is a literal when it is the first or last character in a character class (i.e., it does not indicate a range). For example,  `'a-z'.match?(/[_-]/) #=> true`.